# Contents are rotating with loader

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a loader component in my application for that I have used the following code.

**CSS**

```
#app {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#maincontainer {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #3498db;

    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
}

    #maincontainer:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #e74c3c;

        -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite; 
        animation: spin 3s linear infinite; 
    }

    #maincontainer:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        bottom: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #f9c922;

        -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; 
          animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0%   { 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  
            transform: rotate(0deg); 
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
            transform: rotate(360deg);  
        }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        0%   { 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  
            transform: rotate(0deg);  
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
            transform: rotate(360deg);  
        }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
        <div id="maincontainer">

        I have some contents here 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Loader is working fine but the issue is the content inside the inner div also rotating with the loader. I want the contents to be stable in the page and only rotate the loader. 
Jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ybfcbmsL/)

Can some one please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution by far is going to be to simply put the animation on a different element than the contents you don't want animated.

(Incidentally: it's no longer necessary to include those vendor-specific `-webkit` and `-ms` prefixed CSS elements; `animation` and `transform` have been broadly supported for years now.)

```css
#app {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#spin, #maincontainer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
}

/* Combining the repeated declarations: */
#spin, #spin:before, #spin:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

#spin {
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

#spin:before {
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-top-color: #e74c3c;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

#spin:after {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-top-color: #f9c922;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="spin"></div>
  <div id="maincontainer">
    I have some contents here
  </div>
</div>
```